# How to ensure test data in a file is used only once in JMeter

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to use the data file only once.

For example : I have a data file which has 100 entries and in my test 20 entries are used. i want when i execute the same scenario again then it will start 21 data entries not from 1st.
or it can remove the used data from the file and save the used data into some other file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example, I want to create an account /sign up for a shopping application . if i use the same entries for sign up then it says users already exist. so i want once data is used then it will be removed from the file .

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JMeter solution would be counting the number of lines using i.e. [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) and storing it i.e. into a file using i.e. [__StringToFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringToFile)

On subsequent execution you can check whether the file exists and read the line with offset from the file using i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

With [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) it's kind of easier, for example:

- [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/): its [READ](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/#READ) endpoint has `KEEP=false` parameter, in this case the entries will be removed from the CSV file
- [Redis Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-redis-data-set-an-introduction) has `Recycle Data on Use` setting, if you set it to false the entries will be removed from Redis

In both cases the entries will be removed from data file/data source and on subsequent executions there will be "new" data